# connect users to database entry in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am hoping that someone can help me further in my application.

Here is where I am at. I have general users with roles of "owners" and I have seekers with roles of "seekers". Now, the "owners" create a posting, while the "seekers" accept it.

I hoping someone very well experienced in Rails can suggest the best path and structure to take to do the following;

1.) connect "owners" to their posts in the database when they create a post

2.) connect "seekers" to the post they accept.

So if the "owner1" creates 10 posts, he should be linked to 10 of those posts and no other. Now "seeker1" let say, looks at all 10 posts but only likes 5 of them and clicks on a button to accept 5 of them he picked.

I'm not sure how to have Rails automatically connect everything, any suggestions will help. Haven't found anything on Stackoverflow similar to this yet.

---

Just wanted to rephrase my initial setup and function.

In my application I have;

- a user who with roles can create a job description post. He can edit that, delete it or mark it completed.
- I also have seekers, people who go through all of the posts created by users. Seekers, if they like the post and the description of the job, and they want to do that job, they click a button "Grab it"

So the function I want to create is;

1.) tie users to their posts. Right now, any user can create a post and see all posts. I'd like for them in a certain view to see only the posts they created and no others.

2.) I also want "seekers" to be able to tie themselves in the DB to the job post they want to work with.

Now from my overall understanding of things, and a newbie at it. I'm guessing I would need to update the DB and create 2 new tables. 1 x owners and 1 for Seekers.

Where I am getting stuck is on the controller, how to make my "def new" run after the user submit the form with post details and tie him to that DB object.

Step two as mentioned above would be to use "def grabit" to run when the "grab it" button is clicked by the seeker and tie the seeker to that post also.

So in the end if I ran @job = Joblisting.find(1), I would get the DB table spit out with column 'user' show the user who created this post and the table 'seeker' the name of the seeker working on it. If no seeker of course it would be nil.

Hmmm.. just thinking about it, would email addresses to identify people be alright and suggestible or do you suggest doing some kind of ID for each signed up user.

Any help on this would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert, but I would think something like below would be good.
Both Posts and LikedPosts would contain a :user_id column.
LikedPosts would only also contain a :post_id.

Posts could then be called with

```
User.posts.all
User.liked_posts.all
```

The models would be related like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :posts
  has_many :liked_posts

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

class LikedPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :posts
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it. Gonna try that and see, if it works that should cover the "owner" of the posts. Just have to figure out how to allow "seekers" to mark them :liked_posts

Comment: You can simply do an ajax request when a user clicks the "like" button. Passing both the post id and user id, you would create a new liked_post with those params

Answer (score 1):

Every post has one owner, so that would form a simple one-to-many relationship where a user has_many posts and a post belongs_to a user. A liked post can have many "seekers" though as it appears and a user can "seek" many posts. So that would form a HABTM relation. That would look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :posts
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sought_posts, :class_name => 'Post', :join_table => 'posts_users'

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :seekers, :class_name => 'User', :join_table => 'posts_users'
```

I don't know if "sought_posts" is the best name, but you (hopefully) get my drift. I'm also not 100% sure if the join_table should be specified here, but it won't hurt so I thought I'd include it.

The migration for the HABTM join table would look like this:

```
class CreatePostUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts_users, :id => false do |t|
        t.references :post
        t.references :user
    end
    add_index :posts_users, [:post_id, :user_id]
    add_index :posts_users, [:user_id, :post_id]
  end
end
```

Comment: I think I've got it..... let me rephrase it below what I initially stated I wanted to do, maybe you and others can shine a light on.